# Why rails app is not responding to authentications with postgres db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5.1

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orG49.png)

This is what the error i encountered while running rails s in my local host

Comment: your is stating that you don;t have user model. may be you forgot to tun migration. creating database.

Comment: Run `rake db:migrate` or `rails db:migrate` that will solve the issue. And update or close your question because that is very low quality question. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: This i s my **user.rb**                                                                                                                                                                 
 `class User < ActiveRecord::Base'
   `validates :email, :password, :presence => true
    validates :email, :length => { :minimum =>10 }
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable                           end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is a migration error. You may have created new model with some database attributes. After creating model you have to migrate attributes to your rails app schema.

Run following command from terminal to run migrations

```
rake db:migrate
```